# How can I center an array at a specific index?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to rotate an array so that the element at the given index comes in the middle. Let's say I have:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Centering at index `4` would produce:

```
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```

Centering at index `0` would produce:

```
[3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: what about even lengthed arrays? what is considered as center point for  an array having 2n length?

Comment: @marmeladze yep you're naming it, centering is not the most accurate term that's why i've put it in quote. but you might get the idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-rotate) is your friend:

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4]
arr.rotate(4 - arr.size / 2)
#⇒ [2,3,4,0,1]
arr.rotate(0 - arr.size / 2)
#⇒ [3,4,0,1,2]
```